# python check if values after the path's are same

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program in python, that checks if the values after a string are exactly same.

Contents of list.txt

```
random/directory/file.txt 0 1 a
random/directory/file1.txt 0 1 a
random/directory/file2.txt 0 1 a
```

first one is `str1`, second one is `str2`, third one is `str3`.

note: these strings dont have the numbers and a letter in them, just the path to file.

I tried it with `endswith()`, but that did not work as i want.

Comment: Could you show your code as well?

Comment: `os.path.samefile(<file1>, <file2>)` to compare two paths that could be relative or absolute but not diff directories, `split('/')[-1]` will give you the file and extension part of the path as a string

Comment: Does the string after the path always consist of exactly three elements separated by spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to compare the strings after the first whitespace it is as simple as:

```
str1 = "random/directory/file.txt 0 1 a"
str2 = "random/directory/file1.txt 0 1 a"
str3 = "random/directory/file2.txt 0 1 a"

print( str1.split(" ", 1)[1] == str2.split(" ", 1)[1] == str3.split(" ", 1)[1])
OUT: True

str3 = "random/directory/file2.txt 0 1 n"

print( str1.split(" ", 1)[1] == str2.split(" ", 1)[1] == str3.split(" ", 1)[1])
OUT: False
```

Comment: what if files had different endings

Comment: Updated my answer to compare everthing after the first whitespace, that should ignore the extension

Comment: This will break if the paths contain whitespace. It would be better to take the last three elements from the split.

Comment: That would break if the argument count changes. It is a bit of an open requirement, alternative would be to get the first whitespace after the folder slash and the file extension dot (otherwise it would break with multiple dots)

Comment: If you dont want to use the os library this could be solved by this abomination print(str1.split("/", 1)[0:][1].split(".",1)[1].split(" ",1)[1]) which returns the first whitespace after the last directory and the last dot...